# The Underlying Set of Product Variety in the Classic Language

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

I'm really not familiar with product variety in classic algebraic geometry language(NOT SCHEME).

For $X, Y$ two prevarieties, we can define their product prevariety $X\times Y$ by gluing affine cases. My questions:

1. Is the underlying set of $X\times Y$ the same as the Cartesian product as sets? (I know the topology is not)
2. If $X, Y$ are varieties, is $X\times Y$ also variety?
3. Does the projection maps $p: X\times Y\rightarrow X$ have any property? For example, is it a  closed map?
4. Let $i_{y_0}: X\rightarrow X\times Y$ be $x\mapsto (x,y_0)$ for a fixed $y_0\in Y$. Is this map a closed embedding?

I'm also wondering if there is any reference for algebraic geometry in classic language? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The product prevariety $X \times Y$ is not the underlying set of $X$ with $Y$. For instance, you know as varieties that $\mathbb{A}_K^1 \times \mathbb{A}_K^1 = \mathbb{A}_K^2$, so asking this to be the Cartesian product of sets essentially asks every zero set of polynomials $K[x,y]$ to be of the form $f(x,y) = p(x) = 0$ or $f(x,y) = p(y) = 0$. However, we know that elliptic curves over a field are a thing, so $\mathbb{A}^2_K$ cannot be a product of the underlying sets of $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ and $\mathbb{A}^1_K$.

Comment: I know that the underlying set as 'scheme' may not be the same. By I'm wondering if it is true in the classic language of algebraic geometry? (The language in Hartshorne chapter 1 for example)@Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "prevarieties" I assume you mean what others may call not-necessarily-separated algebraic varieties.

1. Yes, as a set it is the same as the product of the underlying sets.
2. Yes, it is shown in Kempf's "Algebraic Varieties", page 26. Basically it is shown by proving that a product of affine varieties is an affine variety, and then taking an open cover of products of affines from each variety's own affine cover.
3. It is not always closed, but it is open. This can be shown due to the fact that the projection satisfies the axioms of a quotient morphism, which is open.
4. It is closed and if I remember correctly it is in fact an isomorphism onto its image.

I share your frusturation in the search for extensive materials in classical algebraic geometry.

Comment: For answer of 4, I think it is not really intuitive. The image is just a slice of the product. Why they will be isomorphism?

Comment: I actually ment that it is an isomorphism onto its image. Editted my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few words of explanation here? While the first item is the definition, the others have proofs.

Comment: Added some explanation